# Efficient way to retrieve user count in Swift app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a simple Swift meditation app and want to have a feature to allow users to see how many others have installed the app as well ("You're part of a community of 354 other meditators")

My current plan - save a "blank" record on first load to public DB in CloudKit.

Then - each client on login retrieves all the records and counts how many there are?

Is there a better solution.  I could imagine this getting slow if there are lots of users...

Thanks!

Comment: Will your application be accessing a public DB at all other than for the potential option you described above?

Comment: Have you considered using a BaaS service such ss Parse.com?

Comment: Yes my app will access other public/shared info from the public DB in the future (eg release notes, community news etc)

I haven't tried Parse (I'm new to coding) but prefer to involve as few third party components at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of your CloudKit example, as far as I'm aware there is no option to return the number of records, instead CloudKit just returns the actual records in batches (it decides how many to return). However, you may specify a limit of records for it to return.

If you did specify a limit, you would need to continually update it since once the number of records grows larger than the limit it will no longer retrieve them all and your count will be wrong.

This would be a bad idea probably since you will have to continually release app updates to increase the limit (unless you stored this value in some kind of other external DB which would then probably be preferable to CloudKit itself). Basically, CloudKit is probably not the best idea for this.

It would probably be much easier to use a different public DB setup. Either set up your own or use a service like 'Parse.com' which makes setting up and connecting to a public DB very simple. An additional benefit of doing it this way is you can run the count query on the server and just return the count value itself rather than returning all records and counting them locally - very inefficient.